# How to get current tab index in Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabcontrol, flutter-layout

In flutter implementing a tab layout is easy and straightforward. This is a simple example from the official [documentation](https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/tabs/):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            bottom: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: new Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: [
              new Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              new Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              new Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But here is the thing, I want to get the active tab index so I can apply some logic on certain tabs. I search the documentation but I wasn't able to figure it out. Can you guys help and thanks?

Comment: The answer to your problem is here
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65161942/14208424)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The whole point of `DefaultTabController` is for it to manage tabs by itself.

If you want some custom tab management, use [`TabController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) instead.
With `TabController` you have access to much more informations, including the current index.

```
class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => new _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    new Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    new Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          return new Center(child: new Text(tab.text));
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In this example how to get the index ?? i tried adding the lister but after building a particular tab view then the listener was printing the index i want to get the index before building the layout of the particular tab any idea ?

Comment: statefull only?

Comment: Hey @sarveshchavan did you get any solution?

Comment: To get  the index of tabs simply do `_tabController.index`

Comment: not sure why the top tabs are a mess in flutter whereas the bottom tabs are super cool and easy

Answer (score 63):

In this case, using `StatefulWidget` and `State` isn't a good idea.

You can get current index by `DefaultTabController.of(context).index;`.

Follow the code:

```
...
appBar: AppBar(
  bottom: TabBar(
    tabs: [
      Tab(~), Tab(~)
    ]
  ),
  actions: [
    // At here you have to get `context` from Builder.
    // If you are not sure about this, check InheritedWidget document.
    Builder(builder: (context){
      final index = DefaultTabController.of(context).index;   
      // use index at here... 
    })
  ]
)
```

Comment: Wrapping the whole `Scaffold` inside a `Builder` worked for me.

Comment: This should be accepted answer.  Simplest solution requiring the least amount of code modifications.

Comment: I am always getting 0 as the index. Any help??

Comment: looks like something strange implemented... https://flutteragency.com/get-the-current-tab-index-in-flutter/

Answer (score 36):

You can access the current index when the tab is selected by onTap event of TabBar.

```
TabBar(
    onTap: (index) {
      //your currently selected index
    },

    tabs: [
      Tab1(),
      Tab2(),
    ]);
```

Comment: This does not work as desired if the user changes tabs by swiping.  Only if they actually tap on the tab bar.

Answer (score 19):

Just apply a listener on the TabController.

```
// within your initState() method
_tabController.addListener(_setActiveTabIndex);

void _setActiveTabIndex() {
  _activeTabIndex = _tabController.index;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `DefaultTabController` you can get current index easily whether the user changes tabs by **swiping** or **tap** on the tab bar.

Important: You must wrap your `Scaffold` inside of a `Builder` and you can then retrieve the tab index with `DefaultTabController.of(context).index` inside `Scaffold`.

Example:

```
DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
          bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: [Text('0'), Text('1'), Text('2')]),
        ),
        body: _buildBody(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print(
                'Current Index: ${DefaultTabController.of(context).index}');
          },
        ),
      );
    }),
  ),
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't rebuild when the index changes it looks like? I can get the index when the widget is initially built, but it never seems to change / update in the `Builder` context.

Answer (score 7):

**New working solution**

I'd suggest you to use `TabController` for more customisations. To get active tab index you should use `_tabController.addListener`.

Use this **full code snippet**:

```
class CustomTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onItemPressed;

  CustomTabs({
    Key key,
    this.onItemPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomTabsState createState() => _CustomTabsState();
}

class _CustomTabsState extends State<CustomTabs>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;
  int _activeIndex = 0;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: myTabs.length,
    );
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _activeIndex = _tabController.index;
        print('_activeIndex: $_activeIndex');
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        isScrollable: true,
        indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 5.0),
        indicator: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0), color: Colors.green),
        tabs: myTabs
            .map<Widget>((myTab) => Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    width: width / 3 -
                        10, // - 10 is used to make compensate horizontal padding
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color:
                          _activeIndex == myTabs.indexOf(myTab)
                              ? Colors.transparent
                              : Color(0xffA4BDD4),
                    ),
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 5.0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        myTab.text,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ))
            .toList(),
        onTap: widget.onItemPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: really helped me rather than all other answers

Comment: thanks. I modify the code and work fine. if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
        setState(() {
          _activeIndex = _tabController.index;
        });
      }

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the example of Rémi Rousselet, you can do it, the code like this:

```
_tabController.index
```

This will return the current index of the position of your TabBarView

Answer (score 3):

You can add a listener to listen to changes in tabs like below

```
tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4)
   ..addListener(() {
setState(() {
  switch(tabController.index) {
    case 0:
      // some code here
    case 1:
     // some code here
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart the app after this, instead of just using the hot reload. Since the hot reload won't necessarily run the initState for your screen again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing here was working in my case.

I tried several responses so as a result i used a provider to keep and retrieve the current index selected.

First the model.

```
class HomeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedTabIndex = 0;

  int get currentTabIndex => _selectedTabIndex;

  setCurrentTabIndex(final int index){
    _selectedTabIndex = index;
    // notify listeners if you want here
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  ...
  
 }
```

Then i used `_tabController.addListener()` to update my model.

```
    class HomePageState extends State<HomeScreen> {
    
      late TabController _tabController;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: _tabs.length);
        _tabController.addListener(() {
          context.read<HomeModel>().setCurrentTabIndex(_tabController.index);
        });
      }
    
       ...
       
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return DefaultTabController(
          length: _tabs.length,
          child :
            Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
              appBar: AppBar(
                /*iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                    color: Colors.black
                ),*/
                bottom: TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: _tabs,
                ),
                title: Text(_getAppBarTitle(),style: const TextStyle(/*color: Colors.red,*/fontSize: 22.0),)
                ...
                
                )
            )
        );
    }
       ...
    }
```

Finally last but not least retrieve value when you need.

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<HomeModel>(
        builder: (context, homeModel, child) {
          return Text(homeModel.currentTabIndex); // herre we get the real current index
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable in top.

```
    class _MainTabWidgetState extends State<MainTabWidget> {
    
      @override   void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();   
       }
    
      int selected_index = 0;
 }
```

Now set index in Tabbar onTap

```
    onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
      selected_index = index;
    });
   },
```

Answer (score -2):

*This Code will give you index of Active tab , also save the tab index for future use, and when you back to the tab page the the previous active page will be displayed.*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(new TabBarDemo());
    }

    class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {


      TabScope _tabScope = TabScope.getInstance();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          home: new DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            index: _tabScope.tabIndex, // 
            child: new Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(
                bottom: new TabBar(
                  onTap: (index) => _tabScope.setTabIndex(index),  //current tab index
                  tabs: [
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                    new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                  ],
                ),
                title: new Text('Tabs Demo'),
              ),
              body: new TabBarView(
                children: [
                  new Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                  new Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                  new Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class TabScope{ // singleton class
      static TabScope _tabScope;
      int tabIndex = 0;

      static TabScope getInstance(){
        if(_tabScope == null) _tabScope = TabScope();

        return _tabScope;
      }
      void setTabIndex(int index){
        tabIndex = index;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Undefined class 'TabScop'