# Flutter: Changing the current tab in tab bar view using a button

Tags: dart, flutter

I am creating an app that contains a tab bar on its homepage. I want to be able to **navigate** to one of the tabs **using** my `FloatingActionButton`. In addition, I want to keep the default methods of navigating to that tab, i.e. by swiping on screen or by clicking the tab.

I also want to know how to link that tab to some other button.

Here is a screenshot of my homepage.

[image: Homepage with navigation tabs and floating action button]

Comment: How to achieve that bottom widget effect? Is it an image?

Comment: @Muhammad Qasim this is a standard Flutter widget, however, I am unable to find the code. If anyone recognises this bottom widget's name, please let us know.

Comment: you mean floating action button?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need to get the `TabBar` controller and call its `animateTo()` method from the button `onPressed()` handle.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyTabbedPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => new _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    new Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    new Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Tab demo"),
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          return new Center(child: new Text(tab.text));
        }).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _tabController.animateTo((_tabController.index + 1) % 2), // Switch tabs
        child: new Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you use a `GlobalKey` for the `MyTabbedPageState` you can get the controller from any place, so you can call the `animateTo()` from any button.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static final _myTabbedPageKey = new GlobalKey<_MyTabbedPageState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyTabbedPage(
        key: _myTabbedPageKey,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You could call it from anywhere doing:

`MyApp._myTabbedPageKey.currentState._tabController.animateTo(...);`

Comment: Is there callback to update tabView page content from other stateful widget call back trigger.

Comment: But how to pass data between them?

Comment: Yes, how are you able to pass parameters to the destination Widget?

Comment: _tabController.animateTo((_tabController.index + 1) helped me to navigate to next tab. Thanks a lot Chemamolins.

Comment: @FloatingRock animateTo() is not equal to pushNamed(), It's similar to the animateTo() of a list or a scrollview. You can use pushNamed() instead if you would like to pass data and re-build the desired destination screen using that data. I hope you know about the arguments property of pushNamed().

Answer (score 61):

I am super late, but hopefully someone benefits from this. just add this line to your onPressed of your button and make sure to change the index  number to your preferred index:

```
DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(1);
```

Comment: I always love one-line solution :) Thanks a lot man!

Comment: exactly what i wanted

Comment: not worked for me 
it's said that called on null

The method 'animateTo' was called on null.
Receiver: null

Comment: @OmarEssam Please use it inside `DefaultTabController(length: 3,child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) { // here before return }`

Comment: use : TabController.animateTo(1);

Answer (score 10):

You can use `TabController`:

```
TabController _controller = TabController(
  vsync: this,
  length: 3,
  initialIndex: 0,
);

_controller.animateTo(_currentTabIndex);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    bottom: TabBar(
      controller: _controller,
      tabs: [
        ...
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: TabBarView(
    controller: _controller,
    children: [
      ...
    ],
  ),
);
```

And than, `setState` to update screen:

```
int _currentTabIndex = 0;

setState(() {
  _currentTabIndex = 1;
});
```

Comment: Make sure to add the definition of the `_controller` inside the `build()` method. Otherwise, the `vsync: this` gives an error.

Comment: how to listen to index changes ? I cannot find any method listenToPageChange in the `TabController`

Answer (score 5):

[chemamolin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2498179/chemamolins) [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50890108/1009296) is correct, but for additional clarification/tip, if you want to call your tabcontroller "from anywhere", also make sure the tabcontroller is not a private property of the class by removing the underscore, otherwise the distant class will not be able to see the tabcontroller with the example provided even when using the GlobalKey.

In other words, change

```
TabController _tabController;
```

to:

```
TabController tabController;
```

and change

```
MyApp._myTabbedPageKey.currentState._tabController.animateTo(...);
```

to:

```
MyApp._myTabbedPageKey.currentState.tabController.animateTo(...);
```

and everywhere else you reference tabcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to jump to a specific page, you can use

```
PageController.jumpToPage(int)
```

However if you need animation, you'd use

```
PageController.animateToPage(page, duration: duration, curve: curve)
```

---

Simple example demonstrating it.

```
// create a PageController
final _controller = PageController();
bool _shouldAnimate = true; // whether we animate or jump

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (_shouldAnimate) {
          // animates to page1 with animation
          _controller.animateToPage(1, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeOut);  
        } else {
          // jump to page1 without animation
          _controller.jumpToPage(1);
        }
      },
    ),
    body: PageView(
      controller: _controller, // assign it to PageView
      children: <Widget>[
        FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.orange), // page0
        FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.green), // page1
        FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.red), // page2
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way we're able to pass parameters to the destination page the way we can with e.g. `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LogoScreen(color: "red"))` ?

Comment: There is `onPageChanged` callback which would you give you the current page, and hence you can retrieve the parameters accordingly, if I didn't understand your question properly, you can simply ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultTabController(
              length: 4,
              initialIndex: 0,
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "People",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Events",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "Places",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "HashTags",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to solve similar issue but passing methods or controllers down the widget tree wasn't a clean option for me. i had requirement to go back to tabbed page from other non-tabbed routes (back to specific tabs).
following solution worked for me

Inside tabbed page: read route arguments

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final String? tabId = Get.arguments;
       
    _selectedTabIndex = tabId !=null? int.parse(tabId): 0;

    return Scaffold(
    ....
     body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex]['page'] as Widget,
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
     onTap: _selectPage,
    ....);

}
```

Now the calling page

```
onSubmit:() { // or some other event
      // do something here

      Get.offAndToNamed(Routes.homeTabs,
          arguments: TabIndex.specialTab.index.toString());
      //Routes is a const & TabIndex is enum defined somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `TabController` + `Streams`

Pass a stream into the state object. Pass the new tab index through the stream for the state to update itself. Here's how I'm doing it.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabsWidget({Key? key, this.tabs = const [], this.changeReceiver}) : super(key: key);
  final List<Tab> tabs;

  // To change the tab from outside, pass in the tab index through a stream
  final Stream<int>? changeReceiver;

  @override
  State<TabsWidget> createState() => _TabsWidgetState();
}

class _TabsWidgetState extends State<TabsWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _index = 0;
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: widget.tabs.length, vsync: this, initialIndex: _index);

    // Listen to tab index changes from external sources via this stream
    widget.changeReceiver?.listen((int newIndex) {
      setState(() {
        _index = newIndex;
        _tabController.animateTo(newIndex);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.tabs.isEmpty) return const SizedBox.shrink(); // If no tabs, show nothing
    return TabBar(tabs: widget.tabs, controller: _tabController, );
  }
}
```

```dart
// Sample usage - main
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'tabs_widget.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final StreamController<int> tabChangeNotifier = StreamController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tab Change Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Tab Change Demo'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => tabChangeNotifier.add(0), child: const Text('Go Orange')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => tabChangeNotifier.add(1), child: const Text('Go Red')),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => tabChangeNotifier.add(2), child: const Text('Go Green')),
            ],),
            const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            TabsWidget(changeReceiver: tabChangeNotifier.stream, tabs: const [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.orange,),),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.red,),),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Colors.green,),),
            ],),
          ],
        ),), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabChangeNotifier.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

This is how the above sample looks.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Use DefaultTabController instead of a local TabController, high enough in your widget tree, and then you'll have access to it from anywhere in that sub tree.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  initialIndex: initialIndex,
  length: tabs.length,
  child: SizedBox(   // From here down you have access to the tab controller
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SomeWidget(), // Has access to the controller
        TabBar(
          controller: DefaultTabController.of(context),
          tabs:
              tabs.map((tab) => Tab(child: Text(tab.title, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))).toList(),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: DefaultTabController.of(context),
            children: tabs.map((tab) => tab.widget).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

In any point in that tree, you can access the tab controller with DefaultTabController.of(context) and change the tab, like so:

```
DefaultTabController.of(context)?.animateTo(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```dart
class Tab bar

    class TabBarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      TabBarScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _TabBarScreenState createState() => _TabBarScreenState();
    }
    
    final List<Tab> tabs = <Tab>[
      Tab(text: 'Page1'),
      Tab(text: 'Page2'),
    ];
    
    class _TabBarScreenState extends State<TabBarScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    
      TabController tabController;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: tabs.length);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        tabController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              centerTitle: true,
              shape: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
              title: Text("Tab Bar",),
              bottom: TabBar(
                controller: tabController,
                tabs: tabs,
                indicatorWeight: 5,
                indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                labelColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              controller: tabController,
              children: [
                PageOneScreen(controller: tabController),
                PageTwoScreen(controller: tabController),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

class PageOne

    class PageOneScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _PageOneScreenState createState() => _PageOneScreenState();

       PageOneScreen({controller}) {
          tabController = controller;
       }
    }

    TabController tabController;

    class _PageOneScreenState extends State<PageOneScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                tabController.animateTo(1); // number : index page
              },
              child: Text(
                "Go To Page 2",
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.